# rviz qt creator gui

Tags: ros, rviz, gui, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

I have a question.

I would like to develop a GUI. I want this GUI to interact with a robot running the navigation stack, further I would like to insert this GUI in RVIZ so I can have just a single GUI to deal with.

Can some body tell me the best way to tackle this issue.

I know that I can use qt-creator and CMakelist. I can also use ros-qt, which one would be the best and how can they be integrated in RVIZ.

By the way, I am running ros groovy.

In advance thank you for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73864/rviz-qt-creator-gui/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2013-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Personally I use the quick and useful rqt_gui from [rqt](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt), you can integrate RVIZ in rqt_gui by choosing it from the plugins menu but you will have less viewing area if you have other plugins running, one way to solve that would be to close all RVIZ panels except Tools and Time

I've never used qt-creator so I can't comment on which might be better, hope that helps

---

Originally posted by [mobadr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1168/mobadr/) with karma: 86 on 2013-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-08-20**:
Hi,  thanx, ok, sounds interesting, my question now is how to create a GUI based on rqt_gui and then exported or build a plugin

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-08-20**:
The tutorials are good: http://ros.org/wiki/rqt/Tutorials

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-08-20**:
Ok, thank you for the replay, the issue no is that if I need to create my GUI first and then the plugin will call it and then I can visualise it in RVIZ

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-08-20**:
Well, I suspect that if you do the tutorials and understand that code you will be able to answer your question. If you are not familiar with QT maybe you have to read up on that before also.

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-08-20**:
ok, in a few words, I need to create my GUI based on QT, and then create the plugin so it can be visualised by rqt, rigt?

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-08-20**:
I guess I need to create a QWidget-based GUI, what kind of environment you may recommend to create it?

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-08-21**:
I use Emacs to write code to create an GUI. Or maybe I use QT Designer to graphically design how the UI should look and then write code to implement the GUI. All this is explained in the tutorials. Maybe you should read them and try to understand them.

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-08-22**:
I have been through the tutorial, I have to run the python example and I get the fowlloing error: PluginManager._load_plugin() could not load plugin "rqt_mypkg/My Plugin":  do you have a clue? thanks.

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-08-22**:
Moreover, could you tell a bit the .ui file? what is that for? and how to create it, thank you?

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-08-22**:
Had you declared the xml plugin file in package.xml? I use QT Designer to create an ui file. I start it with "designer quad.ui".

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-08-22**:
I have declared it like this  <rqt_gui plugin="${prefix}/plugin.xml"/>

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-09-02**:
Hi, I manage to solve the problem, it was the .ui file, I had and I changed to . Because I created the gui with qt designer.

Now my next issue is to connect a click event in the rqt gui with some ros application. For instance, if I click a PushButtom I want to start the navigation satck. And if I click another Pushbutton I want to control the robot with a joystick etc. In advance thank you :)